# How to escape UI router params in ui-sref

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a list of clients and I want to pass the client name using `$stateParams`

```
<a ui-sref="cmd.projects_by_client_id({
  clientId:{{client.vid[0].value}},
  client:'{{client.title[0].value}}' <-- the issue
})">
  {{client.title[0].value}}
</a>
```

What I have there works for the most part. **My issue is if the client name contains a single quote, I get a lexer error** complaining about an unclosed single quote, obviously.

I am trying to escape the stateParam. I've tried passing the string through a function but the function does not seem to get called. Probably because it is not supported through `ui-sref`

```
<a ui-sref="cmd.projects_by_client_id({
  clientId:{{client.vid[0].value}},
  client:$scope.someUrlEncodeFunction('{{client.title[0].value}}')
})">
  {{client.title[0].value}}
</a>
```

I've search around but I haven't been able to find an answer to this problem.

**EDIT**

I found this works because it is still in JSON format, but I'd like to not have to parse it again:

```
<a ui-sref="cmd.projects_by_client_id({
  clientId:{{client.vid[0].value}},
  client:{{client.title[0]}}
})">
  {{client.title[0].value}}
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `{{}}` there & no need to wrap it with single quotes. `client.title[0].value` will get evaluated against current scope & `href` will get created based on that value.

```
<a ui-sref="cmd.projects_by_client_id({
  clientId: client.vid[0].value,
  client: client.title[0].value
})">
```

Comment: I swear I tried this without the curly braces and it wasn't working...oh well, brain fart of the day. Thank you, works just fine!

Comment: @Ronnie no worries, that expected from developer :) Glad to help you :)